# Color in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have autocomplete element,
the color property warning only works on focus,
any workarounds?

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-jennings-jdqt1b?file=/demo.tsx

I wish the warning color will be all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

First, just add focused prop in TextField

like this :

```
<TextField {...params} color="warning" label="Movie" focused  />
```

Second, add a className to TextField and override label and input style

like this :

```
<TextField {...params} className="warningInput" color="warning" label="Movie"   />
```

and styles:

```
.warningInput .MuiInputLabel-root {
  color: #ed6c02;
}

.warningInput .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: #ed6c02;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, so it's a built in error?

Comment: that's how mui behaves , mui consider it if it has value or focused then change the color

Comment: but when it is on error, it works fine.  the problem is just with the other variants

Comment: that's right because it already consider error as you can pass a error prop, but for others no

Comment: There is problem on hover,
tried to add style but it interferes with the built in error styles.

Comment: aha, could you please change codesandbox ? i will fix it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-jennings-jdqt1b?file=/demo.tsx:143-156

Comment: and there is a problem on disable as well,
should we open a bug on that?

Comment: I fixed it ,  check this out : https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-hoover-xowovl?file=/demo.tsx